# About HTML and attribute href

Tags: php, html, href, attr

Good evening guys, I have a problem with the attribute `href` because I don't know how to access folders, I give an example:

> I stay in root/store/products/details.php
>
> I want to go root/index.php

My answer is : How do I arrive to root/index.php ? I has been trying with ../../index but that didn't worked

Comment: Does it have to be a relative URI?  Why not just use `href="root/index.html"`?

Comment: @GoojajiGreg without a leading `/` that will go to `root/store/products/root/index.html`

Answer (score 3):

If `root` is the base path on your domain, e.g. `example.com/root`, then if you're at `example.com/root/store/products/details.php`, you would have a link like below to get to your root. This `href` will actually work on any page. If you use `../../index.php` it will only work on some pages.

```
<a href="/root/index.php">Root</a>
```

Comment: I has used that but en WAMPSERVER he send me to localhost/index.php but I Want localhost/Machinery/index.php , however TY for your help

Comment: @AlejandroFernandez so it would be `<a href="/Machinery/index.php">Root</a>` instead

Comment: @AlejandroFernandez This is one of the reasons that developing in subdirectories is a pain. Spend a few hours learning how to set up virtual hosts, it will make your life a lot easier in the long run,

Answer (score 1):

This is how I make all of my template links portable.

For files processed Server-Side you would link by using the `SERVER_ROOT` and for links in an -a href=...' you would use the `SITE_ROOT`.

```
define('SERVER_ROOT', dirname( __FILE__ ) . DS);

$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ?
    'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

if (strlen( $url ) <= 10) $url = null;    // For IDE Support

define( 'SITE_ROOT', $url . DS);          // The base URL
```

So to implement the above

```
<a href="<?=SITE_ROOT?>example/morestuff/">Post Score</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<a href="../../index.php">`

### Demo Snippet:

```js
var base = 'https://example.com/store/products/details.php'

var relative = '../../index.php'


var target = new URL(relative, base).toString()

console.log(target)
```

Comment: It's weird, I used that and worked Jajajaja, Thankyou buddy

Answer (score 0):

PHP defaults to index.php so you can link to

`<a href="/root/">Link text</a>`

By prefixing a URL with /, like "/root/" instead of "root/", you are forcing it to read from the root of your webhost or with a VPS the directory of the website.

If you customised the `DirectoryIndex` you can do `<a href="/root/<Your Directory Index>.php">Link</a>`